# Set the min date on the kendoMaskedDatePicker

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am using the kendo masked date picker (Kendo.MaskedDatePicker.js) and I can't find anything that shows how to set the minimum date.

```
$('#StartDate, #EndDate').kendoMaskedDatePicker({
        dateOptions: {
            mask: '00/00/0000',
            format: 'MM/dd/yyyy',
            min: new Date(2017, 11, 1)
        }
    }).parent().parent().removeClass('k-header');
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I believe the min should outside the date options,can you show  kendoMaskedDatepicker.js code

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#StartDate, #EndDate').kendoMaskedDatePicker({
        min:new Date(2017, 11, 01),
        parseFormats: ["MM/dd/yyyy"],
        dateOptions: {
            mask: '00/00/0000',
            format: 'MM/dd/yyyy',
        }
    }).parent().parent().removeClass('k-header');
```

Dojo [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/IlEXih)